# Why image is not showing up in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add image as a background in the container and text on top. Why image is not appearing? What i am doing wrong here?

```
<div className="container-fluid">
<div className="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bgContainer matchingTalent">
                <div className="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 frContainer text-center">
                    <h2 className="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center matchingTalentHeading">
                    Header Text
                    </h2>
                    <p className="col-md-12 text-center matchingTalentText">Test para text to add more in detail.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>

**css**

.bgContainer {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470219556762-1771e7f9427d?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8YnVpbGRpbmd8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60");
 
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  opacity: 0.6;
 
}
.frContainer {
  padding: 5.5em 3em;
}
.matchingTalentHeading,
.matchingTalentText {
  z-index: 5;
  color: black!important;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the "react" part of the problem?

Comment: Thank you for asking to show react part.  I noticed the problem in there and solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

First try this, to see if the url is broken and if the selector is correct.

```css
.bgContainer {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470219556762-1771e7f9427d?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8YnVpbGRpbmd8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Also, trying using container-fluid as a selector

```css
.container-fluid {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470219556762-1771e7f9427d?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8YnVpbGRpbmd8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Resources:

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/)

Comment: Some explanation of why this should help will help future visitors.